# What is wrong with user's last seen data?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, last-activity, profile-page, last-seen

Many times I see some issue with user's last activity.

For example, now I saw user, who asked a question **10 minutes ago**, and when I check his profile, there is shown:

`Last seen 17 mins ago`

So is this bug or what?

**Question:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223575/my-array-has-several-results-but-only-displays-one

[image: question]

**Profile:**

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6518333/tutox-tutoriais

[image: profile]

Comment: [Blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).